How can you appropriately combine multiple loss conditions for an optimization problem
I have a noisy signal (tri-exponential decay) that I am trying to extract parameters from using a global optimization function. The main issue with this is that the loss landscape of the signal has a whole trough of minimum values (just in 6 dimensions) and it is very hard to distinguish between them when triyng to identify the true decay constants. The core idea that I had was, can I augment the traditional mean absolute loss the following way:

where S is a signal, and T is a transform. (e.g. moving average, cumulative sum, magnitude of the fourier transform, etc)
The key benefit I see in doing this is that the true solution will be a minimum in the loss landscape of the transformed representation of the signal as well and that different transformations will highlight different components of the signal. Therefore, we can combine multiple loss landscapes into one that eliminate some regions of our loss landscape that do not represent the true solution.
In my testing I have tried out the following:

None of which seem to reduce the loss any more than just using the best of the losses used in making the combined loss.
A couple of things to note,

I have been using differential evolution as my optimization algorithm because it is fast and I have been doing many computations to try and gather this data.
I have found that taking the predictions from a number of different optimizations using different loss functions (with different transformations) does not really improve upon the best of those loss functions when used individually.

My questions are therefore as follows:

Is the logic in the approach sound, and if so, has this been explored in literature (examples of other people doing a similar thing).
Which of the combination methods would you use and why? (my money is against 3 but otherwise I don't know).
Any overall thoughts would be appreciated.

